# UpdatePanel triggers

Tags: button, triggers, updatepanel

I'm having a hard time with the ASP.NET UpdatePanel. The problem is that my button will not fire its onclick event. I've tried numerous things and simply can't figgure it out. Here is a code sample:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smDefault" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<div style="display: none;">
<a id="various1" class="ltbtn" href="#inline1" style="display:none;"></a>

    <!--  / light box \ -->
    <div class="lightBox" id="inline1">     
        <h2>Nieuw tijdsvak</h2>

        <fieldset>
            <div class="nieuweReactie">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlNieuwTijdsvak" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <label>Start tijd</label><asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTijd" runat="server" CssClass="field datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
                        <label>Eind tijd</label><asp:TextBox ID="txtEindTijd" runat="server" CssClass="field datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnVoegTijdToe" runat="server" Text="Toevoegen"
                            CssClass="btn" onclick="btnVoegTijdToe_Click" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnVoegTijdToe" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>                    
            </div>
        </fieldset>            
    </div>
    <!--  \ light box / -->
</div>
```

My thoughts are that this should be valid, or am i missing something here?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Hmmm still no help.. I think it has something to do with the wrapper div wich has a style property display with the value none; Whenever i remove this property, things work like they suppose to. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: I've found an easy implementable solution myself. [Example](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an easy implementable solution myself. [Example](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)